# Any alternative for ScreenCamera to stream my desktop?

Tags: streaming, video-streaming

As in the topic. Do you know guys any alternatives to screenCamera so that I can stream my desktop (create a virtual webcam streaming my desktop - in games) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ManyCam](http://www.manycam.com/) will do the job.

ScreenCamera will have a major release sometime in the near future that should answer better to users' requirements.

-- *Alessandro Ferri, developer of ScreenCamera*

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with VLC. It will take some tinkering with the settings to get the desired frame rate and bit rate over your network connection for your PC.

Comment: hey, thanks for reply. The VLC as far as I know allows you to stream to one PC given IP address, what I want to do is to create a virtual camera (of my desktop) which I will select when using streaming service like justin.tv . I think it is clear what I want to achieve. Something like www.dyyno.com